# How to detect when the content of a canvas was changed?

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I need to watch the changes in an canvas object (I'm using fabricjs library).

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {isDrawingMode:true});
//I need to watch the changes here -> 
canvas.toJSON();
```

I try out with [Object.prototype.watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) like:

> canvas.toJSON.watch('objects', function(){
>      //dosomething});

But that hasn't worked for me, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your example mentioned `isDrawingMode:true` I think you are looking for a way to detect the drawing on you canvas in free hand mode.

Fabric JS expose a long list of events, as you can read [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events).

So if you want to detect the free drawing on your canvas you can use `path:created` event.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{isDrawingMode:true});
canvas.on('path:created', function(event) {
    //log the svg path  info
   console.log(event.path.path);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The canvas calls it's own events as outlined in this doc: [Class: Canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) where you will see lots of events the canvas emits.

The event for checking if the object is modified is below:

```
canvas.on('object:modified', function(event) {
    // the object that has been modified is in:
    event.target
})
```

Comment: I missed the isDrawingMode param. `path:created` might be the better event to bind to. You can always play with the events listed on this page: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html